# Advanced parse from string to int Python

Tags: python, parsing, python-2.7

I need to get some data's from wikipedia.org.
I have string a = '4 200 000+ articles' , and I need to get int b = 4200000.
I've got this string by BS4, and I've tried to simple parse by int(a), but it's 
obvious that this doesn't work.
Could You help me?

Answer (score 1):

You'd need a regular expression to get numbers out of text like that:

```
import re

int_numbers = re.compile('\d[\d ]*')

def extract_integer(text):
    value_match = int_numbers.search(text)
    if value_match:
        try:
            return int(value_match.group().replace(' ', ''))
        except ValueError:
            # failed to create an int, ignore
            pass
```

The pattern matches a digit followed by 0 or more further digits or spaces.

Demo:

```
>>> a = '4 200 000+ articles'
>>> extract_integer(a)
4200000
```

If you need *all* such numbers in the input text, use `.finditer()` and a generator:

```
def extract_integers(text):
    for value_match in int_numbers.finditer(text):
        try:
            yield int(value_match.group().replace(' ', ''))
        except ValueError:
            # failed to create an int, ignore
            pass
```

Demo:

```
>>> for i in extract_integers('4 300 123 times 42'):
...     print i
...
4300123
42
>>> list(extract_integers('4 300 123 times 42'))
[4300123, 42]
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is remove everything but numbers, you could use something like:

```
>>> x = "500000+"
>>> import string
>>> all=string.maketrans('','')
>>> nodigs=all.translate(all, string.digits)
>>> x.translate(all, nodigs)
```

This will remove all characters from the string except for the digits 0-9.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import re 
>>> a = re.findall(r'[\d ]+',  '4 200 000+ articles' )
>>> print a
['4 200 000', ' ']
>>> [x.replace(' ','') for x in a if x.strip()]
['4200000']
```